# Почему pyautogui обходит(игнорирует) исключения if, elif, else?

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui as pg

print('Выберите число от 1 до 10')
number = input()

if number == 1:
    pg.moveTo(150, 600, duration = 
0.25)
    pg.click()
elif number == 2:
    pg.moveTo(100, 100)
else:
    print("Error!!!")
```

Подскажите, почему pyautogui игнорирует if, но при этом выводит Error
Прошу прощения Админ, не разобрался как код вбивать в теги

Comment: Потому что `input()` всегда возвращает строку, а строка никогда не бывает равна никакому числоу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If не игнорирует и работает как и должно. Проблема только в том, что вы сравниваете число со строкой. То есть если использовать так

```py
...
number = int(input())

if number == 1:
...
```

Или так

```py
...
number = input()

if number == '1':
...
```

То все будет, работать. Причина в том, что метод `input()` возвращает тип данных `string`. И если сравнивать строку и число, как у вас, то всегда условие будет отрабатывать только в `else`

Для понимания

```py
>>> 1 == '1' # это ваше сравнение, всегда будет ложно, чтобы вы не ввели
False
>>> '1' == '1' # сравнение 2х строк
True
>>> 1 == 1  # сравнение 2х чисел
True
```